# Почему приложение которые было сдамплено из памяти не работает?

Tags: ассемблер, reverse-engineering

Основная программа в процессе работы загружает другой PE файл в память и далее переключает контекст на него, после чего сама завершает свою работу. Я сдампил данную программу, но она не хочет запускаться. При запуске возникает ошибка Memory could not be written.

Вот ссылка на дампы
https://yadi.sk/d/XvGBPeWz3TBRe5, пароль 123

Comment: А сама основная программа где? Скорее всего проблема в ней, а не в дампах.

Comment: https://yadi.sk/d/MeYdPLdz3TBq36 - вот основная, пароль clean

Comment: Т.е. исходников нет? Кто кого запускает? Крэкми запускает дамп?

Comment: Конечно исходников нет. Кто кого запускает описал в вопросе.

Comment: Основная программа (какая, crackme?) загружает другой PE файл (откуда, что за PE файл?) Сдампили я так понимаю "другой PE файл". Как дампили? Как его пытаетесь запускать?

Comment: Ответ на вопрос из заголовка - скорее всего потому что в PE файле секции без прав на запись. А когда из другой программы запускается, права для участка памяти все на чтение/запись есть.

Comment: Дампил из памяти с помощью Skylla, восстанавливая таблицу импорта и IAT. Попутно вопрос, а можно как-нибудь права эти при дампе выставить? Либо дамп отредактировать в каком-нибудь редакторе?

Comment: Можно, это просто битики в флагах в заголовков секций. Возможно какой-нибудь PeID поможет.

Comment: Вот ссылка на скрин в момент дампа. Может быть он поможет в постановке диагноза. https://yadi.sk/i/6qGci_E53TBsAP

Comment: Ну, как я и думал - весь блок памяти с правами на чтение-запись (и исполнение к тому же).

Comment: Поможете с флагами? Я в этой теме пока не силен. Возможно в программах DiE либо PE Bear можно выставить нужные флаги. И какие секции нужно поправить? Все? Или какие-то определенные?

Comment: Возможно, я с ними не знаком. Вот нагугленная картинка для PE Explorer: http://www.heaventools.ru/img/sectionedit.png . Это свойства одной секции. Нужное поле - characteristics. Сверху оно в "собранном виде", справа - редактор каждого бита этого поля. Вот сама статья откуда картинка: [Редактор заголовков секций PE файла](http://www.heaventools.ru/pe-explorer-section-editor.htm). В бесплатных продуктах скорее всего примерно тот же функционал.

Comment: https://yadi.sk/d/oKR2P8sn3TBthq - скрины каждой из секций сдампленной программы. Можете сказать все ли с правами доступа  нормально?

Comment: Ну так вроде бы нормально. Пробуйте для всех секций добавить права на запись.

Comment: Добавил. Не помогло. Все без изменений. Вылетает при запуске. Так же если открыть в IDA, то она не может проанализировать файл полностью - на графике ошибка sp-analysis faled

Comment: sp-analysis faled - это просто ошибка определения уровня стека внутри функции. По идее не должно влиять. Возможно не запускается из-за того, что PE заголовок неправильный, тут трудно сказать. Если в IDA в целом показывает вменяемый код, можно вручную пробовать по кускам запускать анализ. Если "невменяемый" (куча разных странных инструкций) - возможно файл упакован.

Comment: Код показывает вменяемый, хочется разобраться почему дамп не работает и исправить это.